# What does this mean? msg 156 when using MERGE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I'm kinda new to programming.

This message appears when I execute my query:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'.

Could you tell me whats wrong with it?

```
 MERGE Table_2 As target
    USING Table_1 AS SOURCE 
    ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID) 

 WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.FirstName <> SOURCE.FirstName 
    OR TARGET.LastName <> SOURCE.LastName THEN 
    UPDATE SET TARGET.FirstName = SOURCE.FirstName, 
    TARGET.LastName = SOURCE.LastName 

 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (ID, FirstName, LastName) 
    VALUES (SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.FirstName, SOURCE.LastName)

 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE
```

Comment: Given merge statement works perfectly fine, just that a semi colon is missing at the end which is a must to terminate a merge statement. Is this the only statement that you are trying to execute?

Comment: Yes sir, thats the only statement im executing, but it returns this :Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'.

Comment: Can you please share the table structures and some sample data to better analyse the reason.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are you sure it's not SQL Server 2005 or the DB Compatibility Level isn't SQL Server 2005? `MERGE` has been introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Dan might be onto something. Try and run `SELECT @@VERSION` and post here what it says?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your database is at the wrong compatibility level and or your server is not SQL 2008 or later.  What do you get when you run:

- `select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name=db_name()`
- `select @@VERSION`

You should get `100` or larger for the first and `SQL 2008` or later for the second.